# error C2039: 'type_name' : is not a member of of 'swig::traits<Bar>'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, swig

I'm unable to SWIG wrap a function that returns a map of pointers to class instances. I get compile errors when the generated SWIG code is compiled.

> error C2039: 'type_name' : is not a member of `'swig::traits<Bar>'`

Here is my .i file

```
class Foo
{ 
... 
}; 

class Bar
{
...
};

%template(MapFooPtrBarPtr) std::map<Foo*, Bar*>; 

std::map<Foo*, Bar*> GetMap();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following typemap code to the .i file before the %template. Note the lack of '*' after the class name in the return string.

```
%{
    namespace swig {
    template <> struct traits<Bar>
    {
        typedef pointer_category category;
        static const char* type_name()
        {
            return "Bar";
        }
    };
    }
%}
```

Got the solution from: http://swig.10945.n7.nabble.com/std-containers-and-pointers-td3728.html